# Open Excel Worksheet to a certain tab based on Date

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am creating a sheet that my maintenance mechanics will use to fill out night-shift reports at the end of their shifts. I have a spreadsheet with a different tab for each date in the format of month.day.year all in numbers. For example, today's tab is 7.17.2016 . I would like for the document to open to the current date so that there is no way that they could fill out the wrong day's tab.

I am new to macro's and only have done a small amount of coding in c++ and worked with matlab, so I need a little babying.

Thank you!

Cole

Comment: If you know required steps to do this manually, then you can record a macro and go through them then once complete stop recording, grab the code from the macro and place into the subroutine that is called when the workbook opens.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808523/open-specific-sheet-according-to-current-date

Answer (score 0):

You need to add, in the workbook_open event,`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`  `worksheets(format(date,"m.dd.yyyy")).activate`  and in the worksheet change `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` put in the same, no need to check if the navigated to sheet name, as you're "hard coding" by using the date where to go, usually, you'd have a little logic in there should it be needed, should you need to, sh is the sheet and target is the cell(s)

Comment: if you place in `Workbook_SheetChange` event no one will ever be able to navigate to a sheet other than today's, including the developer - which i don't think is smart. In `SheetChange` event i would flag for when changes are made to sheets that are not for today so people can be alerted.